# android getIntExtra what is the value for?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

when you want to get an integer from another activity and write for example

```
Intent getData = new Intent();
int test = getData.getIntExtra("ship1", 0);
planets += test;
```

Why does my planets variable add the value from the getIntExtra instead of the actual integer from the other activity. And can someone also explain what that value is for and how to add the actual integer from the other activity to the planets variable.

Comment: This is the mechanism of passing variables between activities in android. What is the confusion?

Comment: I don't know if you mean the number at the end of the `getIntExtra`. If so, this is the default value in case the "ship1" had not been passed from the other Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is your problem. To get the data passed from otther activity you need to get the Intent not to create a new one:

```
Intent getData = getIntent();
int test = getData.getIntExtra("ship1", 0);
planets += test;
```

Answer (score 0):

well i am using this code to get the data from other activity

for sending data

```
 Intent shipping= new Intent(context,NextClass.class);
             shipping.putExtra("ship1", codee);
            startActivity(shipping);
```

for receiving

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            ship= extras.getInt("ship1");
        }
```